# InsertAfter is not working in IE7 but working in FF

Tags: jquery, html

I am using `jquery 1.7.2.js`.

Here is my code that i am inserting after a div,

```
$("<div style="color: red">some text</div>").insertAfter('#main-Div');
```

This is working fine in my FF, but not in IE7.

May i know what will be the reason behind this?

Comment: Could you put that in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: side question : any special reason using version 1.7.2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `.after()`

```
$('#main-Div').after("some text"); // puts the text outside after #main-div
```

not sure what your motto is, you can try `.append()`:

```
$('#main-Div').append("some text"); // appends the text before any other elem 
                                   // in #main-div
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/insertAfter) link,The elements must already be inserted into the document.

You might be looking for

[append](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append) or [appendTo](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/appendTo)

Answer (score 0):

insertAfter works only if the page is fully loaded.

use this:

```
$("#main-div").appened('#some text');
```

or

```
$("some text").appendTo('#main-Div');
```